# Quickblox - onError not called

Tags: java, android, exception, quickblox

I get an exception "W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.quickblox.com": No address associated with hostname"

while creating a dialog but onError is not called.

```
    QBDialog dialog = new QBDialog();
    dialog.setName(name);
    dialog.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);
    dialog.setOccupantsIds(occupantIdsList);

    QBGroupChatManager groupChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager();
    groupChatManager.createDialog(dialog, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {

        }


    });
```

I implement errors handling and one of them is calling a method (createDilog) without a network connection.
Is sth wrong with QB Android SDK?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: It was fixed in version 2.5+